# Navigation Bar Debugging

Tags: css, debugging, navigation

[the text is cascading downwards for unknown reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Q9U.png)

I'm taking a high-school web design class and as an extension project I'm creating a faux restaurant advertisement website. My coding for a top navigation bar is correct as far as I can see and my teacher doesn't know how to help me get the text and navigation box centered and next to each other. All the links work how they're supposed to, they just aren't in the right place >:(
[My css code for navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4A0p.png)

Comment: Next time you submit an question, please submit code in text, not as an image.. haha

Comment: set up a snippet/fiddle/codepen with the relevant css and html so that we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the css property `float: left` from `.topnav a` and make `.topnav li` `display: inline-block`

Sounds like you guys need a new teacher lol. But on the other hand, he makes you find out the problem by "yourself", which is nice.

```css
body {
  background: #2f4f4e;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Palatino;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Takeout Options</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kid's Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Mascot</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Founder</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Back Dumbster: Schedule and Guideline</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```